# C to Perl Translation HMAC SHA1 , data and secret key

Tags: c#, perl, hmacsha1

I want to convert the C code below into perl. Anyone know how to do this? Do you use `hmac_sha1_hex($data, $key);`? Do you use the digest:sha module? I want to sign some data with a key, but use perl instead of C.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web;


namespace Amazon.Cba.Signature.Common 
{
    public class SignatureCalculator
    {
        public SignatureCalculator()
        {
        }

    public String calculateRFC2104HMAC(String data, String key)
    {
        String result = null;

        KeyedHashAlgorithm algorithm = new HMACSHA1();

        Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

        algorithm.Key = encoding.GetBytes(key);

        result =  Convert.ToBase64String(algorithm.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(data.ToCharArray()))); 

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that isn't c; maybe it's c#

Answer (score 2):

I would do this like so:

```
use MIME::Base64 ();
use Digest::HMAC_SHA1 ();

my $result = MIME::Base64::encode_base64(
    Digest::HMAC_SHA1::hmac_sha1( $data, $key ),
    ''
);
```

or if you want a url-safe base64 encoding:

```
my $result = MIME::Base64::encode_base64url(
    Digest::HMAC_SHA1::hmac_sha1( $data, $key ),
);
```

though you can also use the separate Digest::HMAC and Digest::SHA modules together.